# Using Sed after grep to replace inline with an HTML prefix

Tags: html, bash, macos, sed, grep

I have some text in which I want to replace with an actual link.

The text looks like this:

```
Some text here 
[...]
-   CRAN Task View: [Bayesian](Bayesian.html)
-   CRAN Task View: [Cluster](Cluster.html)
-   CRAN Task View: [Databases](Databases.html)
-   CRAN Task View: [Environmetrics](Environmetrics.html)
[...]
End of text here
```

But as you can see, there is no HTML link to the pages. E.g., Bayesian.html should be http://cran.rstudio.com/web/views/Bayesian.html

The final result should be

```
Some text here 
[...]
-   CRAN Task View: [Bayesian](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/views/Bayesian.html)
-   CRAN Task View: [Cluster](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/views/Cluster.html)
-   CRAN Task View: [Databases](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/views/Databases.html)
-   CRAN Task View: [Environmetrics](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/views/Environmetrics.html)
[...]
End of text here
```

So far, I was able to "subset" my text file using the following command:

```
grep "CRAN Task View: \[" $FILE
```

But when I try to pipe to this:

```
sed -e 's|\\([a-zA-Z]*\\)\\.html|http://cran.rstudio.com/web/views/\\1.html|'
```

It doesn't work. How would it be possible to sed inline from the grep command?

I'm on macOS Mojave.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This `sed` should work for you:

```sh
sed -E '/CRAN Task View:/s~\(([^)]+)\)~(http://cran.rstudio.com/web/views/\1)~' file

Some text here
[...]
-   CRAN Task View: [Bayesian](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/views/Bayesian.html)
-   CRAN Task View: [Cluster](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/views/Cluster.html)
-   CRAN Task View: [Databases](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/views/Databases.html)
-   CRAN Task View: [Environmetrics](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/views/Environmetrics.html)
[...]
End of text here
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `/CRAN Task View:/`: Only if line matches text `"CRAN Task View:"`
- `s~`: Substitute
- `\(`: Match a `(`
- `([^)]+)`: Match 1+ non-`)` characters in capture group #1
- `\)`: Match a `)`
- `(http://cran.rstudio.com/web/views/\1)` is replacement that creates a link using back-reference #1

Answer (score 1):

> `sed -e 's|\\([a-zA-Z]*\\)\\.html|http://cran.rstudio.com/web/views/\\1.html|'`
> It doesn't work.

This is a quoting issue. Inside single quotes `'...'` backslashes `\` need no escaping. Bash parses `'\\('` as `\\(` and sends it to `sed` which interprets it as the literal string `\(`. Therefore, you are replacing the literal string **"** *`\(`someLetters`\)\.html`* **"** which never occurs in your file.

You probably meant `sed 's|\([a-zA-Z]*\)\.html|http://cran.rstudio.com/web/views/\1.html|'`.

By the way: `sed` can also do the `grep` part for you. Also, with `-E` you need less backslashes. But since you append the `.html` again, you don't need the group `\(....\)` in the first place.

```
sed -E -n '/CRAN Task View: \[/s|[a-zA-Z]*\.html|http://cran.rstudio.com/web/views/&|p'
```